# Dynamic filter on Django query

Tags: django, python-2.7, search

I want to search in a field given by user.

I have this so far:

```
def search_engine(model, given_field, text):
    # Stuff
    result = model.objects.filter(given_field__icontains=text)
    return result
```

The "given_field" inside filter would be the parameter given in the function, which is a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a dict with a dynamic key generated from `given_field` and then unpack it using `**` to generate keywords arguments.

```
def search_engine(model, given_field, text):
    # Stuff

    filters = {
        given_field+'__icontains': text
    }
    result = model.objects.filter(**filters)
    return result
```

Comment: Perfect!! I was looking for a very pythonic way, and this is great, thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem:

```
def students(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.items(): 
        # this condition will check wether we are passing any filters
            filters = {}
            for key, value in request.GET.items():
                if value != '':
                    filters[key] = value
            students = Students.objects.filter(**filters)
            # we can see only filtred students
        else:
            students = Students.objects.all()
            # we can see all students without any filters when we enter in to page 
    return render(request, 'students.html', {'students': students})
```

Comment: When answering, consider adding more description than just "here is my code". This will help people in the future better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  @Derek C. I will follow from the next time, I have added a comment to the lines where needed so I thought no need for description.